# Android | Google Drive Api Storing Application Data - Using with other users

Tags: android, drive

I would to use Google Drive Api - Storing Application Data to save some files from my app, I see [this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata#what_is_the_application_data_folder).

I would to "share" this storage with other users.
*For example, one use upload an image into his storage, then (checking with my server) another user download it.*

I search but I didn't find anything, is it possible? Or should I use another method?